# How to use SQL query on CSV file in POWER BI Desktop

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, powerbi

We can use SQL Server link between POWER BI and SQL server to make SQL Query on a database. But If I only have CSV file how can I request some information WITH SQL QUERY. In fact we can import CSV file and (I suppose) do some query with the POWER QUERY(it's DAX language I think), but I don't want to use DAX I want to use SQL QUERY like requesting data from SQL Server.

Example of query with SQL Server: `= Sql.Database("LAPTOP-P3DH07C9", "Projet Big Data", [Query="SELECT * FROM MatchComplete"])`

Is it possible or I must use DAX ?

Comment: It's not DAX; Power Query language is "M". And it's very easy to accomplish your goal with it.

Comment: Alright, it's not too complex, but it's a little too bad that I can use what I already know to solve my problem, but thanks a lot !

Comment: You can import csv file to the SQL server and then query it :)

Comment: A CSV file can be connected to directly with the Power BI query editor simply using the GUI. I'm not sure why you want to get SQL involved as an intermediate step.